After updated the Cmake in ubuntu , but the pc told me the version of CMake is too low
I am installing the ROOT (6.32.06) in ubuntu. So I have updated the CMake from 3.16 to 3.2.2. However the information is still displaying " CMake 3.16 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.2.2"! How can I fix it? thank you!

"So I have updated the CMake from 3.16 to 3.2.2." - This is not an update but downgrade: version 3.2.2 is lower than 3.16. Thus you got the error message.
